# How would I do Mesh-Warp image processing in C# or C++

Tags: c#, c++, opencv, image-processing, matrix

How would I perform a 'mesh warp' on an image to re-map the location of pixels.

Here's an ascii-art example. On the left is the input image with a 3x3 matrix of control points and a processed image on the right where the image is 'mesh warped' so that the control points are at different locations.

```
  640x480 image         640x480 image
+--------------+      +--------------+
|     2        |      |1     2     3 |
| 1        3   |      |              |
|              |      |              |
|      5       |  ==> |4     5     6 |
| 4         6  |      |              |
|              |      |              |
| 7     8    9 |      |7     8     9 |
|              |      |              |
+--------------+      +--------------+
```

I've looked at OpenCV, tried its calibrateCamera() but I'm looking for a more arbitrary/free-style remap. OpenCV has remap() but if I understand correctly, it needs a matrix mapping all pixels rather than a smaller matrix of control points. Maybe OpenCV has the ability to generate a matrix that OpenCV's remap() could use. Ideally, the matrix of control points would be NxM e.g. 5 high x 9 wide or even an arbitrary cluster of control points. I don't need to remap colors or intensity - just pixel locations. I'm not limited to OpenCV.

Comment: This post should be reopened, it is a legitimate question now.

Comment: Linear or bicubic interpolation ought to work, although it may need a couple more points on the border (unless you can extrapolate from existing lines to the corners and border mid-points). Start with going from the right image to the left; if that works try the other way 'round.

Comment: You mean determine pixel locations for pixels between the control points using interpolation? That makes sense - I'm just not sure how to do it - thought something might already be available.

Comment: @JimFred Have you found a solution?

Comment: I ended up using EmguCV which is a C# wrapper for OpenCV. I used a  4-point perspective transform which is better than a 3-point affine transform but not as good as a 9-point or spline-mesh pixel mapping transform.